# How to close the notification after speech finished

Tags: java, android

How to keep notification only while speech running?

Main Activity:

```
TextToSpeech tts;

...

public void notification () {
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = 
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this) 
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_volume_up_white_36dp)
.setOngoing(true)
NotificationManager NotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotifyMgr.notify(1, notification.build());
}

...

public void speak() {
    tts=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            notification(); //Call Notification
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            tts.speak("message", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    });
}
```

What is needed to implement notification cancel action and where it should be entered

```
NotifyMgr.cancel(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Method isSpeaking Method to check whether tts is speaking.

```
if(!isSpeaking()){
notifymgr.cancel(1);
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isSpeaking())

Comment: I get Unknown method 'isSpeaking'

Comment: Works with (!tts.isSpeaking).

Comment: Great. isSpeaking is boolean method TextToSpeech class.  the method returns true if the TTS engine is speaking. and that server your requirement i guess.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
public void speakNotification() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NotificationManager NotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (tts.isSpeaking()) {
                NotifyMgr.notify(3, notificationSpeak.build());
            } else {
                speakNotification();
            }
            if(!tts.isSpeaking()) {
                NotifyMgr.cancel(3);
            } else {
                speakNotification();
            }
        }
    }, 1); //1 is the update time
}

public void speakMotd() {
    tts=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            speakNotification();
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            tts.speak("message", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    });
}
```

New handler is needed because the app stops working.